# Undelete Collections in different sessions

Tags: java, hibernate

Consider the case given below.

```
class Person{
@Id
String name;
@OneToMany
List<Address> addresses;
}
```

Suppose in a session I create a person and one address value and save, and in a different session I do a load and when I persist I will add some addresses and I do not want the first address saved to be deleted then what should I do?

Example:

```
Session session1 =  sf.getCurrentSession();
session1.save(person);//person here has an address diff from below
session1.close();
Session session2 =  sf.getCurrentSession();
Person p1=session2.load(person,"Name");
List persA=new Arraylist<Address>();persA.add(new Address(...));
p1.setAddress(persA);
session.merge(p1);
session2.close();//this code is not exact I want to just project concept from here
```

So I want both the addresses to remain in the db and when I eagerly load thru spring data i should get both the addresses! how can i get this behavior?

Thanks all!

Comment: How can you save 2 values in same field ? This is not achievable by a single field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are overwriting the address list by creating the new one. once you load the `Person` do the following:

```
List persA = p1.getAdress(); //get the existing address associated to the person.
persA.add(new Address()); //add new address to the existing list.
```

Comment: I know this resolution but I want to save that `getAdress()` call. I have several such fields in several classes so I cannot keep doing that? Is my requirement possible first of all or I have to do what Rohit has said which is the last resolution for me?

Comment: Do you want to avoid the `getAdderss()` call due to performance worries?

Comment: Yes, but now we have agreed to put it..! Thanks!

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer... but in our application evrtthing is recorded and nothing is deleted... hence I had this above req..!